# Pivot table for loop multiple plots export using pdf pages

Tags: python, pandas, pdfpages

Using pdf pages below results in a pdf without the plots. 
Is it possible to resolve this for plots from pivot tables?

```
import seaborn as sns
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf
pdf = matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages("seaborn.pdf")

# Loop over list 's' for plots
with PdfPages(r'seaborn.pdf') as export_pdf:
    s = ['embark_town', 'class', 'embarked']
    for i in s:
        fig = plt.figure(figsize = [10, 5]);
        ax = titanic.pivot_table(values='fare', columns = i, index='sex', aggfunc='sum').plot()
        export_pdf.savefig(fig, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) to get both `fig` and `ax` then set the `ax` argument of [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

pdf = PdfPages("seaborn.pdf")

# Loop over list 's' for plots
with PdfPages(r'seaborn.pdf') as export_pdf:
    s = ['embark_town', 'class', 'embarked']
    for i in s:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10, 5])
        titanic.pivot_table(
            'fare', columns=i, index='sex', aggfunc='sum'
        ).plot(ax=ax)
        export_pdf.savefig(fig, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Page 1:

[image: page 1]

Page 2:

[image: page 2]

Page 3:

[image: page 3]

Comment: Many thanks, 
typically the addition of bbox_to_anchor = (1,1) for plots places the legend outside the plot. Do you know why this is not the case here?
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10, 5])
        titanic.pivot_table(
            'fare', columns=i, index='age', aggfunc='sum'
        ).plot(ax=ax).legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))

Comment: You're going to have to set `legend=False` in `plot` if you want to move the legend. `titanic.pivot_table('fare', columns=i, index='sex', aggfunc='sum').plot(ax=ax, legend=False).legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))`